# How to fix creation of new objects with misbehaviors at runtime in plataform game (super mario) in flash CS6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I  am developping a plataform game in flash CS6. I created a class called Plataforma which represents a plataform and extended it as Item_Flor class which, by its turn, is a special kind of plataform when collides with Mario shows an item, a flower, to be consumed by mario. Such item is an object of class Flor (the class names are in portuguese).

However, when Mario colides with an object of class Item_Flor the object: i) does not appear in the correct place (i.e, on top of the object of Item_Flor); ii) as Marios moves, the object moves as well in the same direction of Mario like if the attributes x and y of such object were modified by the mario's coordinates; iii) it seems just one flower is created when mario collides with of item ii.

Here is the code of class Item_Flor, the function enterFrameEvents2 verifies when mario collides with an object of Item_flor and creates an object flower (flor in the following) of class Flor:

```
package  {

  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.events.*


  public class Item_Flor extends Plataforma {

    public function Item_Flor() {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents2);
    }

    private function enterFrameEvents2(event:Event):void{

        if(this.hitTestObject(getMario())){      

            var flor:MovieClip = new Flor();
            flor.x =this.x;
            flor.y =this.y-flor.height;
            getRoot().stage.addChild(flor);        
       }

   }
  } 
}
```

The object flor does not appear in any other place in my code, so I dont know what is changing the x and y positions of it when Mario moves.

And, here is the code of class Plataforma:

```
package  {

  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.events.* 

  public class Plataforma extends MovieClip{

    private var _root:MovieClip;
    private var mario:MovieClip;
    private var onTop:Boolean;

    public function Plataforma() {          
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, beginClass);         
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvents);      
    }       

    private function beginClass(event:Event):void{

        _root = MovieClip(root);
        mario = _root.mario;
        onTop = false;          
    }

    public function getMario():MovieClip {
        return mario;
    }

    public function getRoot():MovieClip {
        return _root;
    }

    private function enterFrameEvents(event:Event):void{
      ...
    }
 }
}
```

I would like to know how can I get the place where the flower must appears fixed, such that, it remains standing on such plataform independently of mario movements?

I am pasting a link where you can download the code to compile it and see the remaining code: https://www.4shared.com/rar/r6ppko4Cei/mario-flashCS6.html

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: At the least... Does using a fixed number instead of `flor.x =this.x;` work?
 Something like `flor.x = 50;` should stop the "follows mario around" issue

Comment: Unfortunately, your sugestion is not working. Well, making some tests I figured out that always I create an object at runtime such problem persists in that object. However, If a drag and drop a symbol on the stage before running the game, the problem does not occur with the occurrence of that symbol. Well, I am using a vcam to make a scrolling effect in the game and I deleted the vcam to see what happen and the problem disappeared for all objects created at runtime. But I need the scrolling effect. I dont know what is happening. Thank you!

Comment: The code of vcam is:

vcam.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movements);

function movements(event:Event) {
   vcam.y += (mario.y-vcam.y)/4;
   vcam.x += (mario.x-vcam.x)/4;
}

Comment: I might e wrong but don't you move all platforms and Mario looks like it is standing in the same place? You ad d your flower on the main stage and it is not moving afterwards - just like Mario so it appears the are moving together. You should add the flower to the layer that is moving around mario (probably your container with all platforms)

Comment: Thanks! I changed the statement getRoot().stage.addChild(flor) to just getRoot().addChild(flor); and my problem disappeared. however, I do not understand

Comment: why adding the flower into the stage makes such problem appear. Any idea why using _root  (since  getRoot() returns _root) the problem desapear? Thanks!